# Why is an instantiated HashMap being returned as a java.util.Arrays$ArrayList?

Tags: java

My problem is... HashMap is being returned as a java.util.Arrays$ArrayList

It's happening here:
StudentEntity is being assigned an Arrays$ArrayList.

```
StudentEntity student = (StudentEntity)studentMap.get(1);
```

I tried to use a typed CSV input utility class and it's not working:

```
public class CsvToMapReader <T> {
```

Below I start a the error point:

> public class StudentEntity implements IEntity{
>
> ```
>     @Getter
>     @Setter
>     private int id;
>
>     @Getter
>     @Setter
>     private String name;
> }
> ```

and this IEntity, StudentEntity, is created from a CSV:

> public class CsvToMapReader {
>
> ```
> // Checks for FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassCastException
> public Map<Integer, T> readCsv(String csvFile) {
>
>
>     Map<Integer, T> table = new HashMap<>();    // CSV as table
>     int rowIndex = 0;                             // Row Index. NOTE: 0 is header row
>
>
>     try {
>
>         String row; // Entire row including commas
>
>         // Start at beginning of csvFile
>         BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
>         while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
>
>             String[] data = row.split(",");
>
>             try {
>                 table.put(rowIndex++, (T) Arrays.asList(data));
>             }catch (ClassCastException error){
>                 System.err.println(csvFile + " is not in correct format for CsvToMapReader<T>.");
>             }
>         }
>
>         csvReader.close();
>
>     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
>         System.err.println("No file with name " + csvFile +
>                 "Are the CSV files in the root folder? Ex: ReportCard\\courses.csv");
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
>     }
>
>
>     return table;
> } }
> ```

.

.

.

and even if I change the class type from T to IEntity and also change the

```
public Map<Integer, T> readCsv(String csvFile) {
```

to

```
public Map<Integer, IEntity> readCsv(String csvFile) {
```

then I have more problems.

.

.

.

```
StudentEntity student = studentMap.get(1);
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
        Passes back a java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
        My assumption is from this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to class com.potatospy.ReportCards2.entity.StudentEntity (java.util.Arrays$ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.potatospy.ReportCards2.entity.StudentEntity is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.potatospy.ReportCards2.Application.main(Application.java:41)
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        ˅                      
Map<Integer, TestEntity> testMap = entityMapAccessor.getAllTests();
                                                         .
                                                         .
                                                         ˅ 
public Map<Integer, StudentEntity> getAllStudents() {

    String csvPath = "students.csv";

    Map<Integer, StudentEntity> entityMap = new HashMap<>();

    entityMap = getCsvAsMap(csvPath, entityMap);

    return entityMap;
}
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
public <T> Map<Integer, T> getCsvAsMap(String fileName, Map<Integer, T> entityMap){


    // Return the entity from the repositoryInMem map if it exists     OR
    // Read it from file and load it into the repositoryInMem Map if it doesn't
    if(!repositoryInMem.containsKey(fileName)) {

        // Create a new Map with the right Entity type
        //Map<Integer, CourseEntity> entityMap = new HashMap<>();


        // Get data from CSV
        CsvToMapReader<T> csvToMapReader = new CsvToMapReader<>();

        entityMap = csvToMapReader.readCsv(fileName);


        repositoryInMem.put(fileName, entityMap);
    }

                                            .
                                            .
                                            .
public class CsvToMapReader<T> {
    // Checks for FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassCastException
    public Map<Integer, T> readCsv(String csvFile) {


        Map<Integer, T> table = new HashMap<>();    // CSV as table
        int rowIndex = 0;                             // Row Index. NOTE: 0 is header row


        try {

            String row; // Entire row including commas

            // Start at beginning of csvFile
            BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] data = row.split(",");

                try {
                    table.put(rowIndex++, (T) Arrays.asList(data));
                }catch (ClassCastException error){
                    System.err.println(csvFile + " is not in correct format for CsvToMapReader<T>.");
                }
            }

            csvReader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("No file with name " + csvFile +
                    "Are the CSV files in the root folder? Ex: ReportCard\\courses.csv");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }


        return table;
    }
}
```

The interface for any Entity is IEntity. I've done this to try to make use of typed methods and classes.

```
public interface IEntity {
}
```

Comment: *it's not working*, *have more problems*, *returned as ...* - where?  Please show what you mean and **what** problems you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ignoring warnings about unchecked conversions.  For example:

```
  table.put(rowIndex++, (T) Arrays.asList(data));
```

You should have seen a compiler warning for that typecast.

As a result you are putting a `List` value into a `HashMap<Integer, StudentEntity>`.  And that leads to problems when you try to extract the value from the map.

---

What is the fix?  Not sure, but I am sure that:

1. You cannot use a type parameter in that type cast.  This results in an unchecked conversion, not a type cast.
2. A cast won't convert a `List<String>` or `String[]` to a `StudentEntity`.   The types are not related, so the JVM won't let you do it.
3. To do the conversion, you will need to *create* a `StudentEntity`, and populate it with the values you read from the CSV.

I suspect you would do better by *not* trying to use generics for this.